# Point and click Ubuntu 16.04 bash script randomly alternates output behavior

Tags: shell-script, scripting, process, kill

I wrote and tested the following point and click Ubuntu 16.04 bash script for the purpose of completely killing a mono-service RecorderManager.exe process by literally killing the process id returned by pgrep followed by deleting the lock file.

```
#!/bin/bash
PID=$(exec pgrep -lx "Recorder Manage")
echo $PID
NUMBER=$(echo $PID | tr -dc '0-9')
echo $NUMBER
kill -9 $NUMBER
rm /tmp/My_Recorder.exe.lock
```

After testing it many times, I found this bash script behaves randomly, alternating between : Sometime it outputs  "Killed!", Other times it outputs "10931 My_Recorder.exe" followed by 10931.

Why does this random behavior occur and how might we fix it?

Comment: why use `pgrep -lx ...` then strip out the PID with `tr` when you could just run `pgrep -x ...` and just get the PID?

Comment: @jsbillings, Thank you for your insightful observation. prep -l lists the process name as well as the process ID. Does the fact that I used prep -lx have any connection to the random behavior I noted in thy original question? Or is it some other cause?

Comment: What is the name of the script itself?  Does it match the pattern `Recorder Manage`?  If so, the `pgrep` is finding the script itself in addition to the process you're looking for.  Also, don't use `kill -9` unless you absolutely have to; just use `kill` to send `SIGTERM` rather than `SIGKILL`, which will allow the killed process to clean up after itself, including its own PIDfiles.

Comment: @DopeGhoti, I am glad to hear from you again. Your hypothesis makes perfect sense. Please post it as an answer and I will accept it promptly.

Comment: Do you have pkill? Would simplify your life, I think.

Comment: @Jeff Schaller, Thank you for your comment. I have pkill. How would it simpify life in this case?

Comment: `pkill` is a tool used to kill a process by name.  for example, `pkill foobar` will do the same thing as `pgrep foobar | xargs kill`

Comment: @DopeGhoti, Thank you for explaining pkill. I hope to try it at 8 AM today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the name of the script itself? Does it match the pattern `Recorder Manage`? If so, the `pgrep` is finding the script itself in addition to the process you're looking for, which will then make it effectively a crap shoot as to which will be listed first.

Also, don't use `kill -9` unless you absolutely have to; just use `kill` to send `SIGTERM` rather than `SIGKILL`, which will allow the killed process to clean up after itself, including its own PIDfiles.